# Color detection of balls in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Imagine I have a set of colored balls (e.g. red, blue and green). I would like to find out what color the ball has which is in the frame at a given moment. There will be just one ball in the frame at a given time. Then I would like to track this ball. I have the tracking and directional part working, if I know the color of the ball beforehand.

What would be a good way to detect the color of the ball dynamically though? I have seen some examples ([ball_tracking.py](https://github.com/HassamSheikh/multiple-color-tracking-opencv/blob/master/ball_tracking.py) [or this one](https://pastebin.com/8VmLtRG1)),  where the colors are fixed beforehand and one just iterates over the possible colors constantly. Is this the usual approach? I feel there should be a way without knowing the colors beforehand, e.g. detecting shape first and then finding the color of the shape.

I have fiddled a little bit with `cv2.HoughCircles()` but I get a lot of false positive even for a still image. I also tried the `BlobDecetor` put this approach seems to be even worse.

I would appriciated any feedback or pointers. Please find an example picture below:

[image: Example image]

Here is the code I have for the tracking, if the color is fixed beforehand.

```
# this is heavily based on
# https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/
# https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/21/opencv-track-object-movement/


# import the necessary packages
from collections import deque
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import imutils #pip install --upgrade imutils
import time

#global variables
north,east,south,west = "Up","Right","Down","Left"

defaultGreenLower = (50,97,0)
defaultGreenUpper = (84,255,255)

defaultRedLower = (0, 179, 106)
defaultRedUpper = (38, 255, 255)

defaultBlueLower = (78, 75, 0)
defaultBlueUpper = (140, 255, 152)


windowTitle = "Tracking & Treshold"
hsvStr = "HSV"

def get_arguments():
    # construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-v", "--video",
        help="path to the (optional) video file")
    ap.add_argument("-bf", "--buffer", type=int, default=64,
        help="max buffer size")
    ap.add_argument("-t", "--threshold", help="Direction_detection. Lower = more sensitive. Default: 20",default=20,type=int)

    # color flags
    group = ap.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    group.add_argument("-r", "--red",
        help="track red objects",action='store_true')
    group.add_argument("-b", "--blue",
        help="track blue objects",action='store_true')
    return vars(ap.parse_args())

def callback(value):
    pass


def setup_trackbars(lowerBound, upperBound):
    cv2.namedWindow(windowTitle,0)

    for i in ["MIN", "MAX"]:
        v = lowerBound if i == "MIN" else upperBound

        for j,k in zip(hsvStr,v):
            cv2.createTrackbar("%s_%s" % (j, i), windowTitle, k, 255, callback)

def get_trackbar_values():
    values = []

    for i in ["MIN", "MAX"]:
        for j in hsvStr:
            v = cv2.getTrackbarPos("%s_%s" % (j, i), windowTitle)
            values.append(v)

    return values


def main():
    args = get_arguments()

    # initialize the list of tracked points, the frame counter,
    # and the coordinate deltas
    pts = deque(maxlen=args["buffer"])
    counter = 0
    (dX, dY) = (0, 0)
    direction = ""

    # if a video path was not supplied, grab the reference
    # to the webcam
    if not args.get("video", False):
        vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()

    # otherwise, grab a reference to the video file
    else:
        vs = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])

    # allow the camera or video file to warm up
    time.sleep(2.0)

    #use green as the default color
    if not args['red'] and not args['blue']:
        setup_trackbars(defaultGreenLower,defaultGreenUpper)
    if args['red']:
        setup_trackbars(defaultRedLower,defaultRedUpper)
    if args['blue']:
        setup_trackbars(defaultBlueLower,defaultBlueUpper)
    if args['threshold']:
        direction_detection = args['threshold']





    # keep looping
    while True:
        # grab the current frame
        frame = vs.read()

        # handle the frame from VideoCapture or VideoStream
        frame = frame[1] if args.get("video", False) else frame

        # if we are viewing a video and we did not grab a frame,
        # then we have reached the end of the video
        if frame is None:
            break

        # resize the frame, blur it, and convert it to the HSV
        # color space
        frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
        #flip image
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1 )
        #create copy for overlays
        overlay = frame.copy()

        blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
        hsvFrame = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

        #connect slider to image
        h_min, s_min, v_min, h_max, s_max, v_max = get_trackbar_values()

        # construct a mask for the color set at the slider, then perform
        # a series of dilations and erosions to remove any small
        # blobs left in the mask
        org_mask = cv2.inRange(hsvFrame, (h_min, s_min, v_min), (h_max, s_max, v_max))
        mask = cv2.erode(org_mask, None, iterations=2)
        mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)

        # find contours in the mask and initialize the current
        # (x, y) center of the ball
        cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
        center = None

        # only proceed if at least one contour was found
        if len(cnts) > 0:
            # find the largest contour in the mask, then use
            # it to compute the minimum enclosing circle and
            # centroid
            c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
            ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
            M = cv2.moments(c)
            center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))

            # only proceed if the radius meets a minimum size
            if radius > 10:
                # draw the circle and centroid on the frame,
                # then update the list of tracked points
                cv2.circle(overlay, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius),
                    (0, 255, 255), 2)
                cv2.circle(overlay, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

        # update the points queue
        pts.appendleft(center)

        # loop over the set of tracked points
        for i in range(1, len(pts)):
            # if either of the tracked points are None, ignore
            # them
            if pts[i - 1] is None or pts[i] is None:
                continue

            # check to see if enough points have been accumulated in
            # the buffer
            if counter >= 10 and i == 1 and pts[-10] is not None:
                # compute the difference between the x and y
                # coordinates and re-initialize the direction
                # text variables
                dX = pts[-10][0] - pts[i][0]
                dY = pts[-10][1] - pts[i][1]
                (dirX, dirY) = ("", "")
                # ensure there is significant movement in the
                # x-direction
                if np.abs(dX) > direction_detection:
                    dirX = west if np.sign(dX) == 1 else east
                # ensure there is significant movement in the
                # y-direction
                if np.abs(dY) > direction_detection:
                    dirY = north if np.sign(dY) == 1 else south
                # handle when both directions are non-empty
                if dirX != "" and dirY != "":
                    direction = "{}-{}".format(dirY, dirX)
                # otherwise, only one direction is non-empty
                else:
                    direction = dirX if dirX != "" else dirY

            # otherwise, compute the thickness of the line and
            # draw the connecting lines
            thickness = int(np.sqrt(args["buffer"] / float(i + 1)) * 2.5)
            cv2.line(overlay, pts[i - 1], pts[i], (0, 0, 255), thickness)


        # show the movement deltas and the direction of movement on the frame
        cv2.putText(overlay, direction, (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.65, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(overlay, "dx: {}, dy: {}".format(dX, dY), (10, frame.shape[0] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.35, (0, 0, 255), 1)
        if direction:
            print(direction)


        #add third channel to threshold view (required for side-by-side view)
        display_mask1 = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)


        # combine frames into a single window
        gui = np.hstack((overlay, display_mask1))

        # display frame
        cv2.imshow(windowTitle,gui)

        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        counter += 1


        # if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
        if key == ord("q"):
            print(get_trackbar_values())
            break

    # if we are not using a video file, stop the camera video stream
    if not args.get("video", False):
        vs.stop()

    # otherwise, release the camera
    else:
        vs.release()

    # close all windows
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Post an example input image.

Comment: @fmw42 I updated the question to include an example picture.

Comment: Is the background always the same bland color? If so, you can convert to HSV and get the saturation channel. It will have low saturation for the background and higher saturation for the green. So you can then threshold on the saturation channel image.